# Which browser does Cordova use on Android?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-webview

I am trying to track down a potential bug where video is rendered upside down in my Ionic application.  It works find on Android 5 which reports Chrome version 49.  On Android 6.0.1, portrait video taken from the camera renders upside down.  There the app reports Chrome version 51.  I wanted to be sure the problem was the Chrome version, so I upgraded chrome on the Android 5 device such that Chrome itself is now reporting 51 but to my surprise even after reinstalling the app within Ionic the user agent string is still reporting 49 and of course the video renders properly.

My question is how does Cordova choose a Chrome version?  I thought that without Crosswalk it would use the version of chrome on the device but this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

I am developing an Ionic Cordova app on Android 6.0.1.
I figured out that Cordova is not using the Chrome App as browser. Instead it is using the browser integrated in the "Android System WebView" app, which is updatable in Google Play Store. Actually it is Chrome, but a different version from the Chrome App.

For example at the moment I have installed:

- Chrome: v.86.0.4240.110
- Android System WebView: v.86.0.4240.99

Answer (score 0):

OK I was obviously doing something wrong.  The Android 5 device is now reporting Chrome 51.  Odd that it did not do it the first time.